# Merge Sort - What is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, mergesort

I am having problems with my merge sort code. Each time I run it I encounter a problem with a IndexOutOfBounds Exception, but I can't seem to figure out why... this is the code produced by our professor (who has been known to make mistakes)... anyone spot the problem

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(T[] array, int first, int last)
{
    if(first<last)
    {
        int mid = (first+last)/2;
        mergeSort(array, first, mid);
        mergeSort(array, mid+1, last);
        merge(array, first, mid, last);
    }
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(T[] array, int last)
{
    int first = 0;
    if(first<last)
    {
        int mid = (first+last)/2;
        mergeSort(array, first, mid);
        mergeSort(array, mid+1, last);
        merge(array, first, mid, last);
    }
}
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge(T[] array, int first, int mid, int last)
{
    int maxSize = array.length;
    T[] tempA = (T[]) new Comparable[maxSize];

    int first1 = first;
    int last1 = mid;
    int first2 = mid+1;
    int last2 = last;

    int index = first1;
    while((first1<=last1) && (first2<=last2))
    {
        if(array[first1].compareTo(array[first2])<0)
        {
            tempA[index] = array[first1];
            first1++;
        }
        else
        {
            tempA[index] = array[first2];
            first2++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    while(first1<=last1)
    {
        tempA[index]=array[first1];
        first1++;
        index++;
    }
    while(first2<=last2)
    {
        tempA[index]=array[first2];
        first2++;
        index++;
    }
    for(index=first; index<=last;++index)
    {
        array[index]=tempA[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the method call I use [mergeSort(array, array.length);]

Comment: I think that it should be array.length - 1 in your method call. It seems to me your last variable should be an index not a size

Comment: fixed... thank you. I could swear I tried that a few times.

Comment: if you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help future readers to find what they need (and trust it) and will help to keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your code, its seems that the `last` variable is used as an index in your code.

That's why you can't pass it as a size to your `mergeSort` method, you have to pass `array.length - 1`.

- `array.length` is the size of the array
- `array.length - 1` is the last index of the array